# Swap directories in tree, from /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4 to /dir1/dir2/dir4/dir3

Tags: directory-structure

I've got list of directories like:

- `stats/gauges/stock/market/PLN/EUR/*`
- `stats/gauges/stock/market/USD/EUR/*`
- `stats/gauges/stock/market/PLN/CZK/*`

and hundreds like these. I need to change to order of the currencies, so it becomes:

- `stats/gauges/stock/market/EUR/PLN/*`
- `stats/gauges/stock/market/EUR/USD/*`
- `stats/gauges/stock/market/CZK/PLN/*`

Inside of these directories there are more nested directories and some files.

What I am trying to achieve actually is to fix "naming" in my statistics, this is the format of data storage used by `Carbon + Whisper + Graphite` setup.

What would be the easiest reliable way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Given your example above, if you can be assured that there's always 6 directories, you can swap the last two by doing something like this:

```
find stats -mindepth 5 -maxdepth 5 -type d \    # (Or some other way of generating your list of directories)
| while read dir
do
     mv -v "$dir" "$(echo $dir | awk -F '/' '{ print $1"/"$2"/"$3"/"$4"/"$6"/"$5 }')"
done
```

Throw an `echo` in front of `mv` to check it out first.

If you can't count on the number of directories, I'm sure there's a more generic way of just doing "swap the last two," but don't know off the top of my head.